# js - trim function only working on leading new lines and tabs

Tags: javascript

I am scraping some data from a table and adding to an array, the trim function is only working on leading `\n` and `\t` and still keeping on the leading new lines and tabs.

I looked around on Stackoverflow and used some of the replace functions with no result.

```
const test = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/24741/000002474118000053/glw-20180930x10q.htm'

const request = require('request');

const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(test, (error, res, html) => {
  if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
    // console.log(html)

    const $ = cheerio.load(html)

    const table = $("tr:contains('Cash and cash equivalents')")

    const items = []

    items.push(table.text().trim())

    console.log(items)

  }
})
```

I need `[cash and cash equivalents, 1903, ...]` instead I am getting:

`[ 'Cash and cash equivalents\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at beginning of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t5,291 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at end of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3,865' ]`

Comment: Why are you expecting that output? Copying text from a table will get you tab delimited text.

Comment: trim only works on ends of strings

Answer (score 1):

The `trim()` function will only remove white-spaces from the start and/or end of the string. To remove all occurrences of `\n` and `\t` white-spaces throughout the entire string, consider using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with the following regular expression:

```
someString.replace(/[\n|\t]/gm, '')
```

This basically means "match every \n or \t character on multiple lines (m) globally (g) throughout the entire string, and replace matches with ''"

```js
const inputString = 'Cash and cash equivalents\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at beginning of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t5,291 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at end of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3,865'

const outputString = inputString.replace(/[\n|\t]/gm, '');

console.log(outputString);
```

To integrate this with your code, you could do the following:

```
items.push(table.text().replace(/[\n|\t]/gm, ''));
```

Comment: Rather than alternation, wouldn't a character class be better, and maybe include space? `.replace(/[\t\n]/gm, '')` or `.replace(/[ \t\n]/gm, '')` ?

Comment: @StephenP good point - just updated answer. Thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: I too would recommend considering throwing a `.replace(/\s+/g,' ')` into the mix.  Also FYI in this scenario, the `m` modifier is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting single string line response on your request

[`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) applies to string and removes empty characters only from its head and tail

to achieve you want you can use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) this string by `regex` `/[\n|\t]/` it meas `any tab or any newline`, and then filter this array from empty lines and trim elements

```js
let s = 'Cash and cash equivalents\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at beginning of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t4,317 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t5,291 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tCash and cash equivalents at end of period\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t1,903 \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t$\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t3,865';

s = s.split(/[\n|\t]/)
     .filter(el => el.trim().length)
     .map(el => el.trim()); 

console.log(s)
```

PS: sorry for my english